# Need help in deploying warn using WSAdmin install with JNDI

Tags: websphere, wsadmin, jacl

I am trying to deploy a web application using WSAdmin tool. But it is throwing an error.

JACl script that I am using is :

> $AdminApp install /opt/www/temp/SampleApp.war {-nopreCompileJSPs -nodeployejb -server delivery -cell delivery_cell -node delivery_node -appname SampleApp -contextroot SampleApp -MapWebModToVH {{"SampleApp" SampleApp.war,WEB-INF/web.xml default_host}}}

Error I am getting is:

> com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX7109E: Insufficient data for install task "MapResRefToEJB
>
> ADMA0007E: A validation error occurred in task Mapping resource references to resources. The Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI) name is not specified for resource reference jdbc/app_DB in module SampleApp with EJB name.

From the error above I understand that I need to configure my JNDI with -MapResRefToEJB. I tried to understand this option but getting too confused.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

These errors appear to be caused by the  MapResRefToEJB option in 
the wsadmin command not being set correctly, or the resource it is pointing to 
not existing correctly in the web.xml file.

Additional information on MapResRefToEJB

Options for the AdminApp object install, installInteractive, edit, 
editInteractive, update, and updateInteractive commands 
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_taskoptions.html

Thank you
Note : Opinions are my own.